# Setting up setup.py to install debian packages and python packages

Tags: python, debian, setuptools

I have a python project. I have installed all my python dependencies through pip into my virtual environment venv.
I have also installed a few packages with debian package manager apt with command apt install. I will be later build packages using setup tools and I need to set up my setup.py file.

How do I have my properly setup the setup.py to contain all of the necessary information? I believe I cannot put everything into install_requires as pip and debian packages are two completely different things. How do I set this up?